# guarantee lenovo & ubuntu 14.07

Tags: lenovo, legal

My lenovo yoga 300 fail : the sound is died, and i lose wi-fi regulary. 
This is technicals issues where ubuntu is not implicated i guess; 
But now, when i call lenovo; they say me :

"We don't take back your computer because Ubuntu, you must re-install Windows (windows is deleted on my computer). 
We don't give you again Windows, you must buy it (again) and re-install it yourself."

So what? Is this legal from Lenovo? (I am in France if this is important)
Is this really no others issues for me if not pay Windows? (again! Arrrrgh)

Ty for attention

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, changing software should not make the warranty void. You will be probably able to demand warranty support. Ask more at Lenovo's official support sites or Facebook and Twitter accounts. 
Also see this articles:

[Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Huge-Computer-Retail-Chain-in-UK-Denies-Warranty-If-User-Install-Linux-463177.shtml)

[Consumerist](https://consumerist.com/2012/06/12/newegg-installing-linux-on-your-computer-is-basically-the-same-as-breaking-it/)

[Lenovo Forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-warranty-if-new-operating-system-is-installed/td-p/1079825)